# How to export a multilevel index to excel using OpenPyXl with Index

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, multi-index

How does one export the results of a pandas **multi-index dataframe ** to excel using **openpyxl** with the column headings and index values?

I would assume that I'd need to set index=True within the dataframe_to_rows() method. However, when I do this, it throws a ValueError: stating that it cannot convert IndexLabel values to excel. For example:

> ValueError: Cannot convert ('Elf', 'Elrond') to Excel

What I'd expect to be loaded into excel is something similar to this:

[image]

**My Current Code**

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from pathlib import Path

multi_df = df.set_index(['Film', 'Chapter', 'Race', 'Character']).sort_index()
subset_df = multi_df.loc[('The Fellowship Of The Ring', '01: Prologue'), :]

# Read in TEMPLATE file from which a copy of the Template will be populated 
outfile = 'TEST_Pivot2XL_TEMPLATE.xlsx'
template_filename = 'YYMMDD-YYMMDD_LOTR_TEMPLATE.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Path(Path.cwd() / "ReportFiles" / "Summary" / str(template_filename)))

ws = wb["myPivot"]
for r in dataframe_to_rows(subset_df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

wb.save(file)
```

**NOTE:** I have an existing excel template file with an empty Sheet titled "myPivot" that I want to write my pivot table into.

**The Dataset I am using is here:**
https://www.kaggle.com/mokosan/lord-of-the-rings-character-data?select=WordsByCharacter.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this should do the trick for you:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

df = pd.DataFrame({('A', 'A1'): [1, 2, 3],
              ('A', 'A2'): [4, 5, 6],
              ('B', 'B1'): [7, 8, 9]}).T
print(f'original dataframe:\n {df.head()}')
filename = 'test.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
writer.book = load_workbook(filename)
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet1')
writer.save()
```

output:

```
original dataframe:
       0  1  2
A A1  1  2  3
  A2  4  5  6
B B1  7  8  9
```

Excel file:
[image]

A file named `test.xlsx` should exist in the working directory for the code to work. Note that it will write to the beginning of the sheet and not append to what is already there.

p.s - the assignment to `writer.book` and `writer.sheets` seem useless but the `ExcelWriter` uses them to figure out which sheets already exist and not write new ones instead.

Comment: Thanks, @erap129  I will give that a go tomorrow and mark it as the answer if it works for me.

Comment: I just tested your code @erap129; it works perfectly; thanks for your help with this.